# Effects of lactic acid ingestion

Tags: injury

What would happen if I drink lactic acid?

I use lactic acid to clean an espresso coffee machine and I wonder what injuries could occour drinking it.

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance or have questions regarding policies, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You should not ask personal health questions on this site; however, I do not believe this is a personal health question. I am going to try and find you some authoritative information on the subject and get back with you.

Comment: I voted to close this as a personal medical question, although it could be easily changed so that it's not. The question is also kind of hard to answer without knowing the specific parameters. It is an acid, so drinking a concentrated sample probably wouldn't be too pleasant. However, it is produced naturally by the body and is often present in milk, hence the name. You could drink rat poison if sufficiently dilute.

Comment: I'm OBVIOUSLY not asking for personal medial advice and I OBVIOUSLY not going to drink lactic acid. If I were into it, I would, at least, be nice enough to auto-answer my question :P This is hypothetical of course, since LA is endogenous I wonder if it can be drunk up to some amount and what effects this will have. After all Caffeine is a poison but we drink it anyway.

Comment: @knm241 We do ingest some - every time we ingest some type of milk product.

Comment: @L.B. I didn't realize that milk contains LA thought it sounds obvious. My question however is more on the line of: What if I drink a small glass of LA? What about a glass? a cup? a bottle?

Comment: @knm241 I had a really difficult time finding information on that subject. I thought at least I could cover the basics of what happens.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, don't drink it... And here's why.

Ingesting lactic acid or for some reason having too much of it in your body can cause a variety of health problems ranging from mild to deadly. There are two types of lactic acidosis; the first is called metabolic acidosis and the second is known as respiratory.

Metabolic acidosis - which is what would be caused by ingestion - occurs when the fluids in your body build up too much of the acid and your kidneys can no longer keep up with the demand placed on them. Or they over respond and remove too much base from your body, leaving you acidic.

Respiratory acidosis is caused when your lungs cannot effectively remove CO2 from the blood. A buildup of CO2 leads to a more acidic body chemistry.

Regardless of what the cause of the acidosis was, you can expect some of the following.

**Symptoms of metabolic acidosis:**

~Rapid and shallow breathing

~Confusion

~Fatigue

~Headache

~Sleeplessness

~Lack of appetite

~Severe acidosis can cause shock, organ failure and even death

**Diagnosis of acidosis:**

A series of blood tests will check calcium, sugar and electrolyte concentrations in your blood.

My sources for this information:

[Healthline](http://www.healthline.com/health/acidosis#Prognosis6)

[WikiPedia on Lactic Acidosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactic_acidosis)

Comment: Whoever did the down vote, please do tell me why. I would be very happy to edit my question if necessary.

Comment: Pardon moi, I'm not an expert in biology: So LA will pass intact in the stomach and adsorbed by intestine and make to the bloodstream. Since then it is analogous to the naturally produced LA and I will experience the same symptoms? Assuming the concentration is not high enough to sore my throat

Comment: @L.B. I did not downvote but whoever did probably did so because your answer sounds rather facetious -- i.e, practically speaking, normal/healthy humans would probably have no more trouble tolerating an acid load from some lactic acid solution than they would by simply eating a lemon, for example. So, your answer is simply quite the exaggeration for normal/healthy folks, to say the least!